# Select WHERE Cast - Maintain Order

Tags: mysql

I am trying to maintain the order of the fields here. Any thoughts? This produces a result, but the results come out in varying order.

```
SELECT value FROM field_one WHERE cast(field_number as BINARY(6)) IN

(44,121.3,121.6,77,78,3,2.1,2.3,2.4,2.5) AND lead_id=1234 AND form_id=123
```

Comment: what order are you trying to maintain? field_number as specified in the the IN clause? like 44,121.3 and so on?

Comment: Why the downvote? A round of clarification can clear this up. Order of the field_numbers - yes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `FIELD()` function for a custom order:

```
SELECT value FROM field_one WHERE cast(field_number as BINARY(6)) IN
(44,121.3,121.6,77,78,3,2.1,2.3,2.4,2.5) AND lead_id=1234 AND form_id=123
ORDER BY FIELD(cast(field_number as BINARY(6)), 44,121.3,121.6,77,78,3,2.1,2.3,2.4,2.5)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/833ae4/7

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an `order by` clause in your query.  Without an `order by` the sequence is undefined.

```
SELECT value 
  FROM field_one 
 WHERE cast(field_number as BINARY(6)) IN (44,121.3,121.6,77,78,3,2.1,2.3,2.4,2.5) 
   AND lead_id=1234 
   AND form_id=123
 ORDER BY value
```

Comment: Thanks - I should have clarified better. Order by is fairly simple - I meant the actual field_numbers. Appreciate the fast response though!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to maintain order of values in your IN clause, you can create an order/rank manually like below and INNER JOIN that with your table and then order by that manually created rank.

```
SELECT value 
FROM field_one 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 1 as rank, 44 as val UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 , 121.3 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 121.6 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4, 77 UNION ALL
 SELECT 5, 78 UNION ALL
 SELECT 6, 3 UNION ALL
 SELECT 7, 2.1 UNION ALL
 SELECT 8, 2.3 UNION ALL
 SELECT 9, 2.4 UNION ALL
 SELECT 10, 2.5)T
ON cast(field_number as BINARY(6)) = T.val
WHERE lead_id=1234 AND form_id=123
ORDER BY T.rank ASC
```

Comment: Thanks Tin Tran. This is in line with that I was thinking. I'll give it a go.

Comment: use the other upvoted answer using FIELD() it's faster.